# Showing that K-topology is not path-connected without using compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness, alternative-proof, path-connected

Let $\mathbb{R}_K$ denote the real line in the K-topology, which is the topology generated by the basis $\left\{(a,b)|a,b \in \mathbb{R}\right\} \cup \left\{(a,b)-K|a,b \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$, where $K=\left\{1/n|n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\right\}$. This topology is not path-connected. Suppose there exists a path from $0$ to $1$, which is a continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}_K$ such that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=1$. Because $f$ is continuous, its image is compact and contains $[0,1]$. Since $[0,1]$ is a closed subset of the compact image set, it must be compact, which is a contradiction as there is an open cover $\left\{(-2,2)-K \right\} \cup \left\{(1/n,1)|n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \right\}$ that does not have a finite subcover.

Can this be shown without using compactness? In other words, is it possible to obtain a contradiction from just the continuity of $f$, $K$ and $K \cup \{0\}$ being closed in $\mathbb{R}_K$, and $[0,1]$ being inside the image of $f$?

Comment: Well, compactness in this case is an avatar of the order-completeness of the real line (that's how you prove a closed interval is compact), so you can presumably take essentially the same argument and translate it into one that directly uses the order-completeness instead of going through compactness.  (In general, for reasons like this, asking for a proof that "doesn't use" some concept or another is always going to be fairly subjective and slippery.)

Comment: For instance, you could take a sequence of points in $[a,b]$ that maps to the sequence $(1/n)$, and then give a direct argument that this sequence must accumulate somewhere in $[a,b]$, and thus contradict the continuity of $f$ since $(1/n)$ does not accumulate anywhere in $\mathbb{R}_K$.  Does this proof "use compactness"?  The fact that any sequence in $[a,b]$ has an accumulation point is a manifestation of compactness, even though you can prove it without ever saying the word "compact" or talking about open covers.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, it would be great if you could expand that into an answer. I actually wanted to understand this contradiction at a more fundamental level (such as using convergence/closure/limit points) rather than just throwing in the term "compactness". Is that possible?